# $group with multiple conditions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have many test docs like below in my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e2c5a0d36c55593b74ada5"),
    "priority" : "P1",
    "key" : "IN94909",
    "days" : 21.8344046180556
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e2c5a0d36c55593b74ada5"),
    "priority" : "P2",
    "key" : "IN94904",
    "days" : 35.8344046180556
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e2c5a0d36c55593b74ada5"),
    "priority" : "P3",
    "key" : "IN95409",
    "days" : 5.8344046180556
}
```

I want all the docs grouped by "P1", "P2" and "P3" only if the "days" has exceeded some SLA. Now the SLA is different for P1, P2 and P3.

My resultset should contain only the ones which have exceeded the SLA. Assume the SLA for P1 as 5 days, P2 as 10 days and P3 as 15 days.

Comment: Could you please plain `SLA for P0 as 5 days, P1 as 10 days and P3 as 15 days.`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what was unclear about this question. It made perfect sense to me, and my answer was exactly what the posted wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best done through the aggregation system.

The first step is to select all documents, where the SLA has expired:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $match: { $or: [
        { priority: 'P1', days : { $gt: 5 } },
        { priority: 'P2', days : { $gt: 10 } },
        { priority: 'P3', days : { $gt: 15 } }
    ] } },
```

Then you can group by each priority with a group stage:

```
    { $group: {
        _id: '$priority',
```

And add each document:

```
        docs: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
    } }
```

And close the aggregation:

```
] );
```

Comment: Awesome Derick ! that was exactly what i was looking for and it solved my problem. Sorry if my question was not clear, but you answered riightly !

Comment: @user2983266, it seems that you're new to StackOverflow. In general, if you think and answer answered your question, you should "accept" it (with the big tick).

Comment: Yes, recently started using it actively ! now i have got it accepted, thanks !